Converting Morpho bio to Iso templates in java
I have morpho biometric templates stored in HEX that I need to convert to ISO format so that I can use a lib like sourceafis to compare the fingerprints but unfortunately sourceafis only support ANSI and ISO formats or how else would would I match morpho fingerprints template with ISO or from a jpeg in java.
I have tried to match morpho fingerprints with iso fingerprints with source afis and source afis threw exception that the morpho template not supported.
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Hex string representations of the Morpho and ISO templates (use same for testing)
    String morpho = "722300305EFF8080999A917C64A34D71667A7F7.............";
     
    String iso = "464D520020323000000000A200000102015000C5.....................";
     
    FingerprintTemplate morphoTemplate = new FingerprintTemplate(hexStringToByteArray(morpho));
   
    FingerprintTemplate isoTemplate = new FingerprintTemplate(hexStringToByteArray(iso));


    // Debug: Print template data
    System.out.println("Morpho Template: " + morphoTemplate);
    System.out.println("ISO Template: " + isoTemplate);

    // Perform matching
    FingerprintMatcher matcher = new FingerprintMatcher(morphoTemplate);
    double score = matcher.match(isoTemplate);

    // Determine if the fingerprints match (adjust threshold as needed)
    double threshold = 40; // Example threshold
    if (score >= threshold) {
        System.out.println("Fingerprints match with score: " + score);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fingerprints do not match. Score: " + score);
    }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported image format
    at com.machinezoo.sourceafis.FingerprintTemplate.readImage(FingerprintTemplate.java:139)
    at com.machinezoo.sourceafis.FingerprintTemplate.<init>(FingerprintTemplate.java:66)
    at com.machinezoo.sourceafis.FingerprintTemplate.<init>(FingerprintTemplate.java:47)


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community I have added source afis code
